# Sqlite3 disnake

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord, disnake

Я делал один код и там мне нужен sql, я взял sqlite, я не понимаю почему оно так говорит, просто потому, что он даже ***не создал*** файл, посмотрите мой код, может найдете ошибку:

```
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот готов к работе")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,activity=discord.Game("n!help"))
    global color
    color = random.randint(000000,999999)
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        xp BIGINT,
        lvl INT,
        premium TEXT,
        messages BIGINT,
        guild_id INT
    )""")
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shops (
        role_id INT,
        id INT,
        cost BIGINT
    )""")
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS economy (
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        bank BIGINT,
        vakanc INT,
        staj INT,
        guild_id INT,
        credits INT,
        credit1 BIGINT,
        credit2 BIGINT,
        credit3 BIGINT,
        credit4 BIGINT,
        credit5 BIGINT,
        credit6 BIGINT,
        nad TEXT
    )""")
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (
        name TEXT,
        guild_id INT,
        prefix TEXT,
        color TEXT 
    )""")
    
    connection.commit()
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if member.bot is True:
                pass
            else:
                 
                if cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?", ( member.id, )).fetchone() is None:
                    
                    
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, 0, 1,?,0,?)",
                    ( str(member), member.id, "no", guild.id , ) )

                    connection.commit()
                else:
                    pass
                if cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM economy WHERE id = ?", ( member.id, )).fetchone() is None:
                    
                    
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO economy VALUES(?,100,0,0,0,?,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,?)",
                    (member.id,guild.id,"no") )
                else:
                    pass
```

Вот тут у меня выходит ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/client.py", line 700, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 99, in on_ready
sqlite3.OperationalError: table economy has 6 columns but 14 values were supplied
```

Делал я на disnake

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке же указанно из-за чего ошибка, вы пытаетесь вставить 14 значений в таблицу с 6 столбцами.

Нужно изменить запрос INSERT INTO, чтобы он соответствовал новой схеме таблицы economy. Вот пример исправленного запроса:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO economy VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
(member.id, 100, 0, 0, 0, guild.id, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "no", ))
```

В этом запросе указано 14 значений, соответствующих новым столбцам таблицы economy, в правильном порядке. Таким образом, он будет соответствовать новой схеме таблицы и не вызовет ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Пересоздайте таблицу. Удалите базу данных и запустите код снова.

В вашей таблице 6 столбцов, а при создании указаны 14.

```
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO economy VALUES(?,100,0,0,0,?,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'no')",
                    (member.id,guild.id) )
```

Значит у Вас в таблице нет остальных 8 столбцов.

```
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS economy (
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        bank BIGINT,
        vakanc INT,
        staj INT,
        guild_id INT,
        credits INT,
        credit1 BIGINT,
        credit2 BIGINT,
        credit3 BIGINT,
        credit4 BIGINT,
        credit5 BIGINT,
        credit6 BIGINT,
        nad TEXT
    )""")
```

Comment: Ну вообще то он ее даже не создал я смотрел в своем файле

Comment: Я не знаю что находится в Вашем файле. Я описал Вашу проблему. Как её решать - дело Ваше.